# TomCat servlet unable to access GlobalNamingResources

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Hey there im currently working on a application in tomcat and im trying to access a DataSource thats defined in the tomcat's server.xml. However im unable to access the resource and it will always return an empty DataSource. The servlet is able to access resources defined on the local level. My question is why is my application unable to access global resources?
The exception im getting when trying to access the database is: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

server.xml

```
    <GlobalNamingResources>
       <Resource name="jdbc/AuthenticationDatabase" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="tomcat" password="tomcat" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tomcat" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>
```

AdminPanel.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "adminpanel", value = "/restricted/user-management")
public class AdminPanel extends HttpServlet {
    private List<User> users;

    private final String PreparedUsersSelectQuery = "SELECT active, user_name FROM users";

    private final String PreparedRoleSelectQuery = "SELECT role_name FROM user_roles WHERE user_name = ?";
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context EnvCtz = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource userDB = (DataSource) EnvCtz.lookup("jdbc/AuthenticationDatabase");

    public AdminPanel() throws NamingException {
    }

    protected void ProcessRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection conn = userDB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(PreparedUsersSelectQuery);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                User user = new User(rs.getString("user_name"), rs.getBoolean("active"));
                PreparedStatement roleStmt = conn.prepareStatement(PreparedRoleSelectQuery);
                roleStmt.setString(1, user.username);
                ResultSet roleResults = roleStmt.executeQuery();
                while (roleResults.next()) {
                    user.roles.add(roleResults.getString("role_name"));
                }
                users.add(user);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        request.setAttribute("data", users);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("ListUsers.jsp");
        try {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void init() {

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ProcessRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ProcessRequest(req, resp);
    }

public void destroy() {
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Access to the userdatabase for the purpose of modifying the user data</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/AuthenticationDatabase</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin Panel</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin-user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin-user</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>User Management</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for any and all assistance in this matter.

Comment: What specific error are you getting? As per the Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/globalresources.html), global resources "_are not visible in the per-web-application contexts unless you explicitly link them with <ResourceLink> elements_". Have you set that up?

Comment: (As an aside, I would expect the driver class to be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, unless you have an older MySQL JDBC driver.)